# Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type java.util.Date

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm migrating to Firebase new version and I get the following error when trying to **getvalue from the snapshot**

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type java.util.Date
```

This happens when trying to getvalue from the snapshot in the following method

```
public void getUpdates(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
    Item item = dataSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);
    itemArrayList.add(item);
    itemAdapter.refreshItem(itemArrayList);
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the Item object, but it worked before, so I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm using dates indeed.

**Firebase item structure**

[image: Firebase item structure]

Item object

```
private String title;
private String description;
private HashMap<String, ItemPicture> picturesHashMap;
private Date publishedDate;
private Date deletionDate;
private String condition;
private String delivery;
private String uid;
private int reported;
private boolean given;
private Location location;
private String frontImage;
private String uniqueID;
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase doesn't support **Date** class objects so you need to store them as long/timestamp which you have already done.

`1463845578489` is a long which needs to be stored in a long variable and not a Date

change your variable declaration to

```
private long publishedDate;
```

Then to convert long to a valid Date object you can use this

```
Date d = new Date(publishedDate);
```

Comment: awesome, but when i printed it out, it showed 05.30 when actual time was 12.38 and i used format DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");